# Is there a way to change paths and file names after a package has been installed using NuGet?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm using `NuGet` to download a bootstrap less version.  Unfortunately, it installs the `LESS` files in `/Content/Less`. I would prefer that it installs it to `Content/Style/Bootstrap`.

I can make these changes manually in my solution, but it would be nice to automate this as the package is updated.  I wouldn't mind creating a new `NuGet` package if necessary. I've read about `.transform` and `.pp` files.

Answer (score 0):

I now it's an outdated question but you could just unzip the package. Move the less files into the folder you want, update the nuspec file if necessary and then repack the file again. With powershell and the new ZipArchive/ZipFile class in .net 4.5 this could be done in minutes.

Comment: Can you give specific examples or point us to some resource for how to do this?